# How to use .htaccess to redirect / to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am really confused by the grammar of .htaccess, so I come to ask for some help.

I have a website, let's say, `www.example.com.`

I want to use .htaccess file to redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/newsite/` except for `www.example.com/keepit/`

I mean, like

`example.com` => `example.com/newsite`

`example.com/blabla/bla` => `example.com/newsite/blabla/bla`

But `example.com/keepit/blabla` stays the same as `example.com/keepit/blabla`

I try to use .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/keepit/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It work to change the / to /newsite, but it failed in the need of omitting /keepit

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is only matching `/keepit/` not `/keepit/anything`.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(keepit|newsite) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for your answering. I tried to use this code but it still fails in not redirect example.com/keepit/ to example/newsite/keepit. example.com/keepit should stay in the same.

Comment: That should not happen with this rule. Can you test in a new browser?